# Get spacial content of selected item in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new with android programing and I have a problem with list view
In my app I have to read data from database (name,ID,year) and then add them to listview after that user must select one of
the items and in a new activity again I read data from db and list some of the other Items based on user's selection
Ol at this time In my first activity I read data and add them to listview..To select I must define a listener..right?
I define it like this code

```
enter code here @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_book);

    String SDcardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    String DbPath = SDcardPath + "/Tosca/" + "persian_poem.db";
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);

    try {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        getData();
        db.close();

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
    }

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
            Log.i(TAG, "Listview get Item Pos");
            Peot_ID.putString ("Peot_ID", (String) list.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Intent Book_list_intent = new Intent (Read.this,Book_list.class);
            Book_list_intent.putExtras(Peot_ID);
            startActivity(Book_list_intent);
        }

    });





}
private void getData() {


        try {
        //txtMsg.append("\n");
        // obtain a list of from DB
            String TABLE_NAME = "classicpoems__poet_contents";
            String COLUMN_ID = "poet_id";
            String _ID = "_id";
            String COLUMN_NAME = "poet_name";
            String COLUMN_CENTURY = "century_start";
            String [] columns ={_ID,COLUMN_ID,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY};

        Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME,columns,null, null, null, null, COLUMN_ID);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
               new String[] {COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_CENTURY}, new int[] {android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2}, 0);

    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);



        } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 1).show();
        }


}
```

But here I have a problem..I want to send data of peot_id (Its deffrent from _id column in db) to next activity..Bt I mentioned that
with this code I can get whole row of selected item and I just want part of it(peot_id ) can you help me how to get just Peot_ID from selected
list item?
and I have another question..
As you see in my code I must refer to one spasial listview several times..each time I defined it by this code

```
enter code hereListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_poet_name);
```

How can I define this listviwe one time and use it in several places in my code?sth like a public variable or sth like that
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you see in my code I must refer to one spasial listview several
>   times..each time I defined it by this code

No. Just create one global `ListView` variable list and simply you can access to it from everywhere in your Activity. There is no need to declaring and initialising ListView again in `OnItemClick()` method.

> I want to send data of peot_id (Its deffrent from _id column in db) to
>   next activity..Bt I mentioned that with this code I can get whole row
>   of selected item and I just want part of it(peot_id ) can you help me
>   how to get just Peot_ID from selected list item?

You are using Android's defined basic layout

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2
```

I suggest you to create own `XML` file for row and then simply get whole View from ListView and from View you can get only `ID`.

### Example:

listrow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/addresses_list_selector"
    >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/id_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/name_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/id_column"
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/century_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name_column"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then an usage with `CursorAdapter`:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, c, 
      new String[] {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_CENTURY}, 
      new int[] {R.id.id_column, R.id.name_column, R.id.century_column}, 0);
```

And then for getting ID from row:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                long id) {
   TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.id_column);
   if (id != null) {
      String idString = id.getText().toString();
   }
}
```

### Note:

If you still want to use android's predefined layout, you need to pass into String[] from `ID_COLUMN` and then access to `ID` from row via `row.findViewById(<id>);`

```
String[] from = {ID_COLUMN, NAME_COLUMN};
int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};
TextView id = v.findViewById(android.R.id.android.R.id.text1);
String idString = id.getText().toString();
```

Comment: thanks my friend for your help..I can make it work but I have problem with create one global ListView variable list each time I define It my application forse close..Can you help me how and where I define It?Sorry for my silly question

Answer (score 0):

You do query like this to get a Particular column record alone :

```
Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
              KEY_NAME, KEY_DESIGNATION}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + yourPrimaryKey, null,
              null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
          mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use `onListItemclick()` method like that

//do not forget to override - very  important

```
@Override

public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
 //TODO what you what you have here the vars position - position of the selected item in list
// and also the id so you can easy trace what selection done the user
// you can play with this 

}
```